# How do you learn to read package documentation and LaTeX typesetting concepts like glue and boxes (primitives)?

Tags: packages, typography, documentation, primitives, glue

I'm having trouble reading documentation from packages. It seems like there's something wrong with the way I'm reading them. How should I read them, in order to learn how to use the packages correctly and efficiently?

Also is there a place where you can learn typography related topics in LaTeX like glue and boxes? I don't find it talk all that much, and if they do they don't teach me why that's necessary. I haven't learn the details of typography other than fiddling with MS Word.

And I would like to learn how to make is so that the fonts and font size aren't too long for the average characters per line.

Comment: What packages are you talking about? Sometimes `texdoc` opens up the implementation documentation and not the user documentation (or something totally different because the manual has a different name that the package).

Comment: The TeXBook covers all aspects related to primatives of the underlying TeX system.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'm talking about how to read user documentation to learn how to use that particular package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes How do you learn how to use them correctly though. Does the TeXbook teaches that?

Comment: Actually, in everyday use of LaTeX and its packages you shouldn't have to worry about glue and boxes. These are low level implementation details, and user documentation usually does not mention them (except when documenting the actual package code in the appendix, which you need not consult in order to use the package).

Comment: @gernot I think this may be outside the scope of the question, but how do you learn to space things correctly. \hspace and \vspace and margin spaces and such. I don't know wherether I'm adding too much space or something.

Comment: @AdrikIvanov Well, then start from the top and read your way to the bottom. If the manual doesn't explain how to use the package then it isn't a manual or at least not a good one. Some manuals have examples, some packages provide only two macros. Some have good support on this site. There is no general approach.

Comment: in a document you should basically never be adding space at all, so if you are using vspace and hspace, you are using too much space

Comment: Both the KOMA-script documentation (`scrguide.pdf`) and the `memoir` manual have some material about typography and margin setup.

Comment: @AdrikIvanov Most people nowadays use either LaTeX or ConTeXt, but not bare TeX, and in these systems, you should hardly ever worry about the details of formatting (like `\hspace`, `\vspace`, `\hbox` etc). This is what these two formats do for you. So best start with a tutorial/intro to LaTeX or ConTeXt, like https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf or https://github.com/contextgarden/not-so-short-introduction-to-context

Comment: Manuals vary in style.  Some are reference manuals.  Others include tutorials.  Some like to dicuss the source code and how they work.  The modern approach to computer sicience is to treat programmers like idiots and hide how things actually work, since it will only confuse them.

Comment: Besides LaTeX and ConTeXt there is also OpTeX. First 29 pages of its documentation is user level documentation. Then you can read about TeX principles and its primitives, for example from the document TeX in a Nutshell (27 pages). Now, you are able to full control your typesetting. No packages are needed so you needn't read a package documentation.

Comment: The above comment by @DavidCarlisle is generally correct, but: If you are writing a non-academic work, such as fiction, and you need to move things for decorative effect, then you would manually add space.